# How to calculate a RPN expression having two different data types in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, calculator, rpn

The following program is suppose to calculate an expression with the possibility of having two different data types , `Float` and `RDD`. I already created an RPN from the infix expression and now I am trying to perform calculations on them. 
Note: I have also overloaded :+,-,/,* for doing calculations on `RDD` and `float`.

```
 def calcRPN(s: String): RDD[(Int,Array[Float])] =
     (s.split(' ').toList.foldLeft(Nil: List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]) {foldingFunction}).head

def foldingFunction(list: List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]], next: String): List[Either[Float,RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = (list, next) match {
     //apply * on inputs
     case (Right(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "*") =>{(sv.*(x,y)) :: ys}                                   //both RDD sv is another class containing overloads
     case (Left(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "*") =>{sv.*(x,y) :: ys} //x being float
     case (Right(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "*") =>{sv.*(x,y) :: ys} //y being float}
     case (Left(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "*") => (x * y) :: ys                                                      //both float
     //apply + on inputs
     case (Right(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "+") => {(sv.+(x,y)) :: ys}                              //both RDD
     case (Left(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "+") =>{(sv.+(x,y)):: ys} //x being float
     case (Right(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "+") =>{(sv.+(x,y)):: ys} //y being float
     case (Left(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "+") => (y + x) :: ys                                                      //both float
     //apply - on the inputs
     case (Right(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "-") => {(sv.-(x,y)):: ys}                               //both RDD
     case (Left(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "-") =>{(sv.-(x,y)) :: ys} //x being float
     case (Right(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "-") =>{(sv.-(x,y)):: ys} //y being float
     case (Left(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "-") => (y - x) :: ys                                                      //both float
     //apply / on the inputs
     case (Right(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "/") => {(sv./(x,y)) :: ys}                              //both RDD
     case (Left(x) :: Right(y) :: ys, "/") =>{(sv./(x,y)) :: ys} //x being float
     case (Right(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "/") =>{(sv./(x,y)):: ys} //y being float
     case (Left(x) :: Left(y) :: ys, "/") => {(y / x) :: ys}                                                        //both float
     case (xs, numString) => numString.toInt :: xs  //**
     case (xs, pathxml) => sv.getArrayRDD() :: xs //***

   }
```

I know this code is ugly sorry about that. I can make it shorter but right now I need to make it work then brush it up!
So in the ** part it is working for two numbers but I added *** to make it accept `RDD` as well. Don't know if it works for both `Float` and `RDD`! plus I have faced the following error because of using `Either` and apparently `Left` and `Right` are  not helping me here!

```
 [error] type mismatch;
 [error]  found   : Either[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]
 [error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]
 [error]         (s.split(' ').toList.foldLeft(Nil: List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]]) {foldingFunction}).head
 [error]                                                                                                             ^
```

I also tried `Scalaz` but it made it more complex.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want to ask/achieve. I think it would help if the code were readable.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg I tried to make it better, sorry about the mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first things first, lets split up things for a better understanding:

```
val creepyListOfoperatorsAndStuff: List[String] = s.split(' ').toList

val eitherList: List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = 
  creepyListOfoperatorsAndStuff.foldLeft(
    List.empty[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]
  ) (foldingFunction)

val headEither:Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = eitherList.head
```

The head of that List is an Either. Thus neither a Float nor a RDD. 
That means we have to decide whether it is a Float or a RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]. 
If you are **REALLY** sure head contains an RDD, you can just do:

```
headEither.right.get
```

A better way to do this might be to deal with both cases:

```
headEither.fold[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]](
  // function to convert a Left() result to the RDD you want
  fa = someFloat => <code to get to the RDD you want>, 
  // this is a function to transform the Right() result to what is desired 
  // as RDD is what you want you can just return the input
  fb = anRDD => anRDD
)
```

Now onwards to the cases ** and ***:

in

```
case (xs, numString) => numString.toInt :: xs  //**
case (xs, pathxml) => sv.getArrayRDD() :: xs //***
```

The second case seems unreachable, because both cases match the same input. You would probably be better off using regex to match the strings you expect there. I am not exactly an expert on regular expression matching but something like the following might point in the right direction.

```
val Numeric = """(\d+)""".r
// don't forget to put the matched string into a group
val XmlPath = """<some regular expression that matches your expected xml path""".r

...

case (xs, NumericString(numString)) => numString.toInt :: xs  //**
case (xs, XmlPath(pathxml)) => sv.getArrayRDD() :: xs //***
```

However, there are more essential problems in theses two cases:

```
case (xs, numString) => numString.toInt :: xs  //**
```

xs would be a List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]].
Thus I have to wonder, does this compile?

```
numString.toInt :: xs
```

If so then numString.toInt is probably converted to Float and then to Left[Float]. But I'm just guessing.

```
case (xs, pathxml) => sv.getArrayRDD() :: xs //***
```

While I donn't see what ***sv*** might possibley be and where it comes form, it might be ok, with the regex matcher.

I would only be able to help with that with more information form you.

Comment: thank you,  I wrote the regex as follow for both number and path : 
`val number = """^([0-9,.]+)$""".r`  
 `val pathIdent = """hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))""".r`
well I am going to try your way, but the problem I ran into so far is that I have this `Either[..]` and the results that I want to save should be just an `RDD` and I have a run time about that, having the following part : `val FinalResult = Left(rpn.result.left).asInstanceOf[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] ` to change it to `RDD`, I get this error:`ClassCastException: scala.util.Left cannot be cast to RDD`

Comment: Either is a container of which you want the content. So try changing `Left(rpn.result.left).asInstanceOf[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]` to `rpn.result.left.get`. Though, from the code above the RDD would be Right, not Left, thus `rpn.result.right.get`

Comment: Sascha YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu